# Pytorch permute not changing desired index

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am trying to use the `permute` function to swap the axis of my tensor but for some reason the output is not as expected. The output of the code is `torch.Size([512, 256, 3, 3])` but I would expect it to be `torch.Size([256, 512, 3, 3])`. It doesn't look like I can use flip to switch 0, 1 index. Is there something i am missing? I wish to change the tensor such that the shape is (256, 512, 3, 3).

Reproducible code:

```
import torch

wtf = torch.rand(3, 3, 512, 256)
wtf = wtf.permute(2, 3, 1, 0)
print(wtf.shape)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers provided to [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.permute.html#torch.Tensor.permute) are the indices of the axis in the order you want the new tensor to have.

Having set `x` as `torch.rand(3, 3, 512, 256)`.

- If you want to invert the order of axis: the initial order is `0, 1, 2, 3`, you want `3, 2, 1, 0`:

  ```
  >>> wtf.permute(3, 2, 1, 0).shape
  torch.Size([256, 512, 3, 3])
  ```

  Inverting axis order is essentially the transpose operation:

  ```
  >>> wtf.T
  torch.Size([256, 512, 3, 3])
  ```
- If you just want to invert *and* keep the order of the last two: original order is `0, 1, 2, 3` and resulting order is `3, 2, 0, 1`:

  ```
  >>> x.permute(3, 2, 0, 1).shape
  torch.Size([256, 512, 3, 3])
  ```

The difference between the two options is that the last two axes of size `3` will be swapped.